# WCF Reliable session sample example

Tags: wcf, session

Is anyone know about  good sample example for WCF Reliable session? How to implement WCF Reliable session?
It is best if example would include main funda like

How to get message acknowledgement at clientside?
How to get message order and sequence no?
How to implement different three types of reliable session?